# Renamed file replacement always being updated

Tags: version-control, merge, mercurial

In my Mercurial repository I have a situation where a single file is always being updated on every merge.  It's a complex situation (which I'll try and explain) and I'm not sure this question is going to get a good reception...

I have two main branches, `Development` and `Master`... where all changes in `Development` are merged into `Master` on release, and the `Master` branch is tagged with version number accordingly.

A couple of months ago I renamed a file in the `Development` branch (from `ViewOffer.aspx` / `.aspx.vb` / `.aspx.designer.vb` to `MakeOffer.aspx` / etc) for naming consistency.  That renamed set of changes was committed into the repo.

In order to safe-guard any instances where the `ViewOffer.aspx` was called (via bookmarks, etc) I created a new `ViewOffer.aspx` with a very simple redirect to `MakeOffer.aspx` and committed that to the repo.

After it was released, I merged the `Development` branch into the `Master` as per usual... but it is only now that I've noticed that every time I now merge from `Development` to `Master` it **always** updates the `ViewOffer.aspx`.

I realise this isn't a big issue, as the file is exactly as it should be... but it annoys me that the file keeps updating.

Is there any way that I can stop it updating each and every time I do a merge?

---

*Update*

Here is a shot from TortoiseHG showing the last merge to take place...

[image]

You can see that `ViewOffer.aspx` has been merged, despite the fact the file hasn't been touched for over 2 months.  (And there have been a lot of merges in that time.)

There is something that has gone wrong due to the renaming of the `ViewOffer.aspx` to `MakeOffer.aspx` and the creation of a new `ViewOffer.aspx`.

Comment: Can you be more exact: in what way does the merge result have the "file exactly as it should be" and at the same time the file "keeps updating". Does it mark the file as having a change but the changes are immaterial?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Edward, I apologise for not being clear... but it's not easy to be clear.  That's exactly what I'm struggling with... it would appear that the file is identical in the two branches (i.e. the file is exactly as it should be), but the date-time on the file is updated each time the merge happens.  I will add a screen shot to show my TortoiseHG screen

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Update to `master` and use `hg revert -r Development ViewOffer.aspx` and commit. This may convince hg going forward that that file is actually the same. Test in a disposable clone before you try it for real though. `:)`

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't had any effect `:(` Merge from `Development` to `Master` still includes `ViewOffer.aspx`

Comment: Even changing and committing `ViewOffer.aspx` in the `Development` branch, then merging `Development` into `Master`... it's STILL `getting` the file on each `update`. I hate computers

Comment: Congrats on finding your own answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of playing, I've finally resolved it... although I'm still totally at a loss to explain why it happened in the first place.

The way I did it was the following...

- Update to `Development` branch
- Make a change to the `ViewOffer.aspx` file and commit
- Update to `Master` branch
- Delete `ViewOffer.aspx` file and commit
- Started merge from `Development` branch to the current `Master` branch.  At this point I was shown the following prompt from TortoiseHG:

> remote changed ViewOffer.aspx which local deleted use (c)hanged version or leave (d)eleted

- Selected `changed` and completed the merge

Now when I `update` between `Master` and `Development` the only file to update is the `.hgtags` (as expected).

And when I make any change and merge `Development` into `Master` the `ViewOffer.aspx` is no longer listed as one of the files.